# Is it possible to call a function contained in an addon (__init__.py) already installed in blender

Tags: python, add-on

Is it possible to call a function contained in an addon (`__init__.py`) already installed in blender, through a script of another addon always installed?

The function in question is a simple `(self, context)` with no input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Actually the next version of the glTF export addon (for upcoming Blender 2.82) will contain a new ability for 3rd-party addons to place glTF extensions into the exported file.  The [code for this feature](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/63d3705933689adf1180cccab1e73327c9b44bc8/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py#L356-L366) looks something like this:

```
    if bpy.app.version < (2, 80, 0):
        preferences = bpy.context.user_preferences
    else:
        preferences = bpy.context.preferences

    for addon_name in preferences.addons.keys():
        try:
            if hasattr(sys.modules[addon_name], 'glTF2ExportUserExtension') or hasattr(sys.modules[addon_name], 'glTF2ExportUserExtensions'):
                extension_panel_unregister_functors.append(sys.modules[addon_name].register_panel())
        except Exception:
            pass
```

In the code above, all addons are searched (via `preferences.addons.keys()`), but of course you could limit your search to a specifically-named addon, if desired.

Once an addon is found, `hasattr` is used to look for a specific class name within that addon.  It will call a `register_panel` function within that class, to register the custom extension's options into the glTF file export UI.

Comment: Very helpful! At the moment this function is not contained in a class, can it be accessed anyway?